# Git: How to make a file look like in other commit in one step?

Tags: git, patch

Basically, what I want is

```
git diff HEAD branch1 -- foo.txt > patch.txt;

git apply patch.txt
```

**How do I do this in one step?**

And, side question: How can I specify a mask for files, like, `**/*.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out individual files from branches (well, any commit) like this:

`git checkout branch1 -- foo.txt`